# Download through Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

Hello I am trying to add a download bottom for lightbox. The use were unable to click on the image directly, so currently I redirect them to the page of the image when they click on the download bottom.

However, I would like to allow the user to download the image directly as soon as they click on the download bottom. Below is the simplified code, but I can only change this part: **function(){window.location = $(this).attr('href'); return false}**

```
<a class='lb-download' href='www.XXXX.com/picture.jpb'></a>
<script>
 $('.lb-download').on('click', function(){
    window.location = $(this).attr('href'); return false})
</script>
```

Thank you so much!
Edit: Yeh, sorry for the syntax error, I have corrected it, but it was mistake. My real problem is how can I force download instead of going to the page of the image?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error here

try

```
 $('.lb-download').on('click', function({
        window.location = $(this).attr('href'); 
        return false});
```

The key points are the `dot` before the className and the position of the parentheses.

Comment: I am sorry for the syntax error. I have fixed it, but my main problem is that I was not able to force download. Instead, the method leads me to the page of the picture.

Answer (score 0):

When you click an anchor with a href, it changes the windows location to the href.
Right now you're doing exactly what the anchor does with your javascript ?

To download the image when the anchor is clicked, you can use the download attribute in newer browsers

```
<a class='lb-download' href='www.XXXX.com/picture.jpg' download="picture.jpg"></a>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xY6WD/)

In older browsers you need to link to a page that sets the right content disposition headers, and passes the image as an attachment.

Comment: My problem is that the javascript "doesn't" do what the anchor does, so this solution doesn't help, but I appreciate your comment.

Comment: The javascript does ***exactly*** what the anchor does, setting the window.location to the anchors href is what the anchor does when you click on it without any javascript.

Comment: I added the download attribute with the name of the file to the anchor. However, when the window.location is set to the href, I was brought to a new page instead of downloading the image. Did I do something wrong? You can check out the webpage here: http://www.sigmachapter.org/pictures/Photo_Gallery/Fall_2013__20130815/RMI_Info_Session__20131202/RMI_Info_Session__20131202.php

Comment: By the way, the second cross at the bottom right is the bottom that triggers the "window.location = $('.lb-download').attr('href')